how to keep a string in class file and access it in scala?
I am keeping one string value in a class file. I want to get this string in another scala main function. How do i get the string abc in main scala code.
package integration.utils


object schemaStructure  {

  class schemaStruct {

    def schemaJson: String =
      """
                  map<
                    string,
                    struct<
                        path:string,
                        type:string,
                        optional:string,
                        defaultValue:string
                    >
                  >
                """

  }
}


Just for the record, the beginning was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78333114/how-to-maintain-a-generic-class-and-import-it-in-specific-scala-codes

schemaJson can now be just a val, not def. What is the reason to keep it inside a class? Why not to keep it in an object (for example lifting it a level above)? Then it can be imported or referenced without instantiating.

I am new to scala.. i am just following the ways that i can find in stackoverflow. let me know how to do that?

schemaJson can now be just a val, not def.
schemaJson seems to be just a constant now, you can reference it without instantiating a class.
You can keep it in an object, for example lifting it a level above
package integration.utils

object schemaStructure  {
  val schemaJson: String = """..."""
}

import integration.utils.schemaStructure

schemaStructure.schemaJson

or
import integration.utils.schemaStructure._

schemaJson

Or you can put it into companion object of class
package integration.utils

object schemaStructure  {

  class schemaStruct // do you need this class?

  object schemaStruct {
    val schemaJson: String = """..."""
  }
}

import integration.utils.schemaStructure

schemaStructure.schemaStruct.schemaJson

or
import integration.utils.schemaStructure.schemaStruct._

schemaJson

Surely, you can keep a val in a class, then you'll have to instantiate the class like you did. Or you can put a val in a trait and extend the trait.
Try to learn basics of Scala:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html
https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/scala/

Thanks for clearly explaining it..it cleared the concept for me

@ShankarPanda In Scala 3 val definitions can be top-level https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-toplevel-definitions.html

val schemaJsonObj=new schemaStruct();

val schemaJson = schemaJsonObj.schemaJson;

